# svg different render result in chrome and safari with same linearGradient id

Tags: html, svg

[Codepen Here](https://codepen.io/minhuang0/pen/JvmQPR)

The `SVG` above is inconsistent with chrome and Safari, Is chrome rendering different from safari in finding id ?

The following svg only linearGradient corresponding color inconsistent, but the same reference id

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

            <defs>
                <linearGradient id="MyGradient">
                    <stop offset="5%"  stop-color="green"/>
                    <stop offset="95%" stop-color="gold"/>
                </linearGradient>
            </defs>

            <rect fill="url(#MyGradient)"
                x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"/>
        </svg>
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

            <defs>
                <linearGradient id="MyGradient">
                    <stop offset="5%"  stop-color="red"/>
                    <stop offset="95%" stop-color="pink"/>
                </linearGradient>
            </defs>

            <rect fill="url(#MyGradient)"
                x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"/>
        </svg>
```

I known Every id must be unique. my question is why same id safiar diffrence with chrome

[image]

Comment: Every id must be unique. Your file is invalid.

Comment: This is not a valid SVG!! are you trying to have to boxes one is yellow & green and the other is red & pink ?

Comment: @RobertLongson I known Every id must be unique. my question is why same id safiar diffrence with chrome;

Comment: @Adam Thanks, I know that my ID is the same. My problem is not that I want to implement two different colors of SVG. I want to ask the difference between the two browsers.

Comment: Who cares really, stop doing invalid things and your problem will go away. This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The concept of XY problem was known for the first time, and the relevant answer was read. The questions I mentioned were based on the wrong conditions and thanked for your answers;

Comment: You can't get the answer for that till you use the right code and a valid elements, because browsers can act differently with same bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a valid code, but you might need to change some of the values all up to you.

Code:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 268 115" style="enable-background:new 0 0 268 115;" xml:space="preserve">
<linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="7.9984" y1="57.7264" x2="107.9984" y2="57.7264">
 <stop  offset="0.1" style="stop-color:#FEDF00"/>
 <stop  offset="0.9" style="stop-color:#21B24B"/>
</linearGradient>
<rect x="7.7" y="7.7" style="fill:url(#SVGID_1_);" width="100" height="100"/>
<linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="155.9984" y1="57.7264" x2="255.9984" y2="57.7264">
 <stop  offset="0.1" style="stop-color:#B9529F"/>
 <stop  offset="0.5356" style="stop-color:#D73D5C"/>
 <stop  offset="0.9" style="stop-color:#ED2024"/>
</linearGradient>
<rect x="155.7" y="7.7" style="fill:url(#SVGID_2_);" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, I known is a valid code. But why does safari and chrome render inconsistent

Comment: even with my new `SVG` I posted? still rendering deferentially in safari

Comment: No problem with using SVG above, is expected rendering